# Hide input value attribute from the dom

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

For some reason when react is updating the input value, the value is showing up in the DOM.
At the moment I'm using this code:

```
< input type="password" id="password" value="anytext" />
```

Is there any way to have the text in the value property hidden for security reasons? Maybe something like this:

```
< input type="password" id="password" value />
```

I'd appreciate everyone's input.

Comment: That's not supposed to happen. Can you show the relevant code for the updating?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-snyder-3o2dd?file=/src/App.js

here is the code

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like this behaviour does not happen:

```js
class Demo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { password: 'test', test: '' }
        setInterval(function() {
            document.getElementById('test').innerText = 'ATTRIBUTE: ' + document.getElementById('password').getAttribute('value');
        }.bind(this), 200);
    }
    render() {
        return <div><input id="password" type="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={(e) => this.setState({password: e.target.value})} /><pre id="test">ATTRIBUTE: {this.state.test}</pre><pre id="value">VALUE: {this.state.password}</pre></div>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: it only shows up once someone starts typing in the input field

Comment: and as my example shows, the attribute stays null, even when typing.

Comment: @dave https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-snyder-3o2dd?file=/src/App.js look at this, react is displaying the values here

Comment: ah, I see, that's because you're using a "pure" component, so it is re-rendering the whole input on every state change.  You can just do it like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-frost-swkp3?file=/App.js and it works the same but you don't see the value in the DOM